Angular - current version of NOde is not supported
I'm confused.
I'm trying to start on a new Angular app.  I'm currently using Angular 14, and if I run "ng version", it tells me that it's using Node "20.9.0 (Unsupported)", with a message saying that this version isn't supported:

The odd thing is, if I ask to view the list of Node versions which I have installed, v20.9.0 isn't listed.
And I haven't PhotoShopped this image.. why is there a blank line at the top of these results ?

And, as the image shows, if I try to uninstall this version of Node, it says I don't have it installed.
So, Angular is complaining that it is running with an unsupported version of Node, which I don't actually have installed.
The obvious solution...  using "nvm use" to say that I actually want to use v14.21.3 of Node (which is compatible with Angular 14).
But when I do that, nothing changes...

One last (desperate) attempt:

Before I miserably go back to programming with GW Basic, What am I missing ?

Did you try to set the default alias in nvm? what is the result of "node --version"?

Run which node. It'll tell you which location of node it's trying to run

It sounds like it is using the system version of node. You can change it by running nvm alias default 14.

You probably try to solve a problem that doesn't exist. Did you face with difficulties with the use of Node 20? This is not an error but warning that could have no side effects. Angular CLI 14 has the requirement "node": "^14.15.0 || >=16.10.0", so technically 20 is supported, and 16 is the last known at that moment. Generally the devs would avoid the use of >= if there was strict dependency on Node version, notably the use of binaries

@EstusFlask no, Angular doesn't support Node 20, there are multiple bugs filed for it, that have all been closed due to inactivity. Such a frustrating ecosystem
